# implicit cast (U32 to U8) does not raise warning

Tags: c, gcc, casting, codeblocks

I compiled the following code on Code::Blocks - gcc :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

void test_print(uint8_t test_var);

int main()
{
    uint32_t var = 100000U;

    test_print(var);

    return 0;
}


void test_print(uint8_t test_var)
{
    printf("test_var = %d\n", test_var);
}
```

Why does it not raise any warning ?
It seems weird to me since I am implicitly casting an U32 to a U8. (which should be avoided since information will be lost in the process)

Comment: Did you test `-Wall` ?

Comment: It doesn't have to. This conversion is perfectly legal. Yet I presume it might warn with some warning settings.

Comment: This is very often done on purpose as a way of deliberately discarding high bits, or when one knows that they are not important or are already zero.  So if the warning were on by default, it would probably just annoy most people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to use the `-Wconversion` flag to gcc, which will pick up on this:

```
[dbush@db-centos7 ~]$ gcc -Wconversion -g -Wall -Wextra -o x1 x1.c
x1.c: In function ‘main’:
x1.c:11:5: warning: conversion to ‘uint8_t’ from ‘uint32_t’ may alter its value [-Wconversion]
     test_print(var);
```

This is one of those flags that isn't included in  `-Wall` or `-Wextra`.